# Decode protobuf without proto files

Tags: protocol-buffers, decoder

I would like to decode protobuf data and running into some decoding challenges.

1> **Example of the protobuf data**: `0a06282c0241057a10011805220d080510bea3f493062a03010c1628f1a6f493063002382b4001481482010f383634333233303532343736343839`

2> **Decoding online** (e.g. via https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/) **works fine**

3> Decoding via **protoc.exe is not working**

- protoc.exe --decode_raw < measurement01_bin.txt (have tried HEX or BIN as input)
- Result: Failed to parse input.
- Question: What am I not doing correct?

---

4> Further I would like to add protobuf decoder in a cloud solution (in-memory) and ideally not be dependent on protoc (in my environment it is almost impossible to run an exe). So I am looking for a **stand-alone parser / raw decoder in run-time**  and not using proto files.

- Question: Do you have idea for me on how I could set this up?

Thanks a lot

Comment: when I try to input the data you give in `protobuf-decoder`, itdoesn't seem to be parsed properly, it's giving weird values. How did you get the protobuf data ?

Comment: The data is coming out of an IoT sensor.

Comment: Then if you are really in for the challenge, you should try to decode it following the encoding/decoding rules that your can find on the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#:~:text=To%20understand%20your%20simple%20protocol%20buffer%20encoding%2C%20you,indicates%20that%20there%20are%20further%20bytes%20to%20come.)

Comment: Thanks for the link Clement .. interesting. Not my preferred way forward ... will read up first.